# Remove Telephone numbers using Regular Expressions in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, text-analysis

I am trying to remove telephone numbers from a bunch of documents that i have parsed using [tika](https://tika.apache.org/) but I do not succeed.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soGVL.png) taken by [regex101 validator](https://regex101.com/). As you can see, phone numbers are skipped.

The same example in text format is the following:

> "Something here
>
> and something here 9, but (I have something here as well), 123456, Hi guys!
>
> +39.1234.325636     +39.321.1234567
>
> sex male | date of birth 16/12/1927 | nationality italian
>
> some stuff   "

This is my Regex (I am not an expert in this field):

`(\(00\d{2}\)|\(\+\d{2}\)|00\d{2}|\+\d{2})[\. ]??3\d{2}[\. \-]??\d{2,4}[\. \-]??\d{2,4}$`

**Notice that +39 (or 0039) is fixed and the first 3 in the second telephone number is also fixed.**

Do you have any suggestions?
Many thanks.

Comment: You may add more test cases about these phones to show the pattern more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on regex101 validator given your input:
`(\+|00)39\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`

Comment: Hi Arius! Many thanks! I have modified your Regex and now it takes all the numbers.

`(\+|00)39[\. \-][0-9]+[\. \-][0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

This is one more regex `/((?:\+39)|(?:0039))+[0-9. ]+/gm`. which will help to locate your telephone numbers

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/14)

Comment: It can capture a space at the end where it shouldn't.

Comment: @Arius: then please change `[0-9. ]` to `[0-9.]`. And in this case the space between numbers will not be matched.